# Uncaught ReferenceError: startPause is not defined for simple button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a button that sends an alert dialog box to the window but for some reason I'm getting this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: startPause is not defined." What am I doing wrong?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgwawupw/

And the code is here:

```
<button onclick="startPause()">Start</button>

$(function(){
  function startPause(){
   alert("A");
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate problems. First, get your javascript out of your HTML. Second, `startPause()` is not defined in the global scope.

```
<button id='clicker'>Click Me!</button>

function startPause(){
    alert('A');
}

$('#clicker').click(function(){
    startPause();
});
```

Make sure you put the `script` tag at the end of your `body` element then you don't need the wrapper like you have in your code.

Comment: I have the code in an html and js file that isn't the problem. So should I not be using an "onclick" event syntax? Pros and cons?

Comment: What I meant was you should not try to make an inline js call in your html `<button onclick='startPause()'>`. Nothing wrong with onclick but you need to set the handler in the js file by using the id, class, or name of the html element you want to bind the event to. Also the `$(function(){` or its sibling `$(document).ready(function(){` wrappers are not necessary if you put your js file's script tag at the end of the body element rather than in the head.

Comment: Ok, but just out of curiosity how would I set up the syntax with "onclick" in my html? I'm still confused on how that would look

Comment: @Stack That's a very basic thing. You define some kind of element identification (id, class) in the markup, and then attach a callback function to that identification.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this, and you should put your JS in `body` or `head` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcubmq44/) - note the settings in the top left):

```
<button onclick="startPause()">Start</button>

function startPause(){
    alert("A");
};
```

This way your function will be in global scope. When you set `onLoad` or `onDomready` in JSFiddle, you are wrapping your function in an event callback, and thus move it from global scope.

If you need or want to use jQuery, go Jared's way. That way you bind click event using jQuery and don't let the browser do it. This way you have more control and can move your function from global scope.

Answer (score 0):

A function defined by a function expression inherits the current scope. That is, the function forms a closure.

On the other hand, a function defined by a Function constructor does not inherit any scope other than the global scope (which all functions inherit).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Which means because you are not making an assignment as

```
 $(function(){
    startPause = function(){ //var was skipped purposely
        alert("A");
    };
 });
```

In case you still need to use it in $(function() {}); make a global object with a namespace

```
 var stackoverflow = {};
 $(function(){
    stackoverflow.startPause = function(){ //var was skipped purposely
        alert("A");
    };
 });


 <button onclick="stackoverflow.startPause()">Start</button>
```

but best practice would be to use

```
$(element).on('click', function() {});
```